# app installation problem after publishing app on google playstore

Tags: java, android, android-studio

recently i upload application on google playstore and user can see my apps on google playstore but the problem is that they cannot install it, because it shows cannot install it, right my apps status is production. i want to know that what will be the app status when user can start installing my apps

link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vamp.byteplayer

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8j7F.jpg)

Comment: Remember to accept existing answer or ask additional details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your app is either set to not be available to or is incompatible with all/some devices.

How to see compatible devices: [google's help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en)

> After you've uploaded at least one app bundle to Play Console, you can view the catalog of available devices and review which devices are compatible with your app. To help ensure the widest availability of your app, review your supported and excluded devices lists regularly.

short version:

1. Go your console account
2. Release > Reach and devices > Device catalog
3. Check if there are any devices compatible with your app

How to add target devices:
(continue in device catalog)

1. Mange devices
2. add device
3. Pick (all supported)

Additionally you might want to check app manifest whether it excludes devices. [Manifest compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#compatibility)

> The manifest file is also where you can declare what types of hardware or software features your app requires and, by extension, which types of devices your app is compatible with. **Google Play Store doesn't let users install your app on devices that don't provide the features or system version that your app requires**.